# Add border to MUI DataGrid Row

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

im trying to style Material UI DataGrid rows to have borders, something close to this screenshot (I censored some information, but u get the idea) [image: MUI DataGrid Image]

The problem I have is that I can't get the right border to appear ( codesandbox below )

So far I tryied to style the global class `.MuiDataGrid-row` with `border: 1`, all borders except the right are being applied, I don't understand why.

Also with this approach, the first row have double bottom border because the second row top border is overlapping and it looks weird, if u can give me a hand with that too would be great!

[image: Edit nameless-leftpad-xfyou7]

Comment: Here's a start: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-payne-knpqo5?file=/src/userList.tsx

Comment: From my understanding, you need a line separating each column.. right?

Comment: @SteveGomez Thanks for the demo, I tryied that approach but I don't want borders where there is no Rows. I want something like this, given your demo example: https://i.imgur.com/JKVq8xv.png

Comment: @LucasFernandez Gotcha -- I've updated the Sandbox. You may have to do something along those lines unless someone else has a better suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

[image: after the suggested changes]
There are two methods

**METHOD 1:** (simple)

Add `showCellRightBorder={true}` to your `Datagrid`component

**METHOD 2:** (provides customization)

Add the following css to your `sx` prop of `Datagrid` Component..

```
CODE TO BE REMOVED:
// "& .MuiDataGrid-row": {
//   borderTop: 1,
//   borderBottom: 0
// },

CODE TO BE ADDED:
"& .MuiDataGrid-cell": {
border: 1,
borderRight: 0,
borderTop: 0,
// add more css for customization
},
```

Comment: for more info, look into documentation here.. https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this approach is not solving the issue, right border of rows is still not showing, see screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/jDOJ0wR.png

Answer (score 3):

Add `showCellVerticalBorder` to your `DataGrid` component for body cell borders, and `showColumnVerticalBorder` for borders in the header

Answer (score 0):

Datagrid automatically sets the row width to 'fit-content', which cuts off the right most border. To fix this, all you need to do is manually set the width of the row to your desired size using the "& .MuiDataGrid-row" global class. In my case it looked like

```
"& .MuiDataGrid-row": {
  border: "1px solid lightgray",
  borderRadius: "5px",
  backgroundColor: "white",
  width: "calc(100% - 2px)",
  marginTop: 3
},
```